# Find 10 entries within x time period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a sql call that pulls up the ip of a user clicked my website x pages within y times. Example 10 pages within 30 seconds. 
I will probably do it as a stored procedure bringing in the page and time variables.

The table will have the columns `datetime`, `ip` and `pageurl`.

Sample data below should return this user's `ip` as he had 10 pages within 1 minute (as an example)

```
2014-01-02 17:29:53.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:29:54.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:02.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:03.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:07.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:08.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:15.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:17.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:18.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:18.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:31.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:32.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:36.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:37.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:40.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:40.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:41.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:41.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:44.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:47.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:48.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:51.000 1.1.1.1
2014-01-02 17:30:51.000 1.1.1.1
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also, tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The `having` clause is what you want.

```
 select ip_address, count(*) records
 from whereever
 where whatever
 group by ip_address
 having count(*) >= 10
```